# Overwrite css of an external widget

Tags: html, css

I load this widget using iframe

http://www.weather.gr/gr/gr/widgets/weather_w10.aspx?points=3

But the font doesnt look good on my site, I need to change it with another font I use it in my site. How can I overwrite the css and load my own font-family?

Also, is there any way to display: none (hide) the url logo?

Comment: This is probably a task better suited for Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Can you copy the widget to your own site?

Comment: Another option would be to get rid of the iFrame altogether, make an AJAX call to get the HTML from weather.gr, and load that into a DIV on your page.

Comment: No you can't change the `CSS` if the iframe src is an external site.

Comment: This may work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/217833/1669208